# Retriving multiple images from the database using entitiy framework asp.net4.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, sql-server-2008-r2, asp.net-4.0

I have made a Movie rental system, in which the user logs in, i want to show him the top 3 rented movies and that to in the form of images. so how can i bind multiple images from the database.

I'm using asp.net 4.0 and entity framework for connecting to the sql server 2008R2 for storage.

I'm a beginner in this technology, so bear with me.

Thanks

Comment: You need to use a data control like GridView, ListView, Repeater, and load a collection of images and bind it to the control. Search for asp.net data binding.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you use a `Gridview` or `Repeater` control to show the list.

If it is `GridView`, you can use `TemplateColumn` and Add a `ImageControl`, use a `ImageHandler` to get the images from the database.

How to create a handler:

```
public class SignatureHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        int recordid = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["recordId"]);
        Movie movie = GetMovie(recordid);
        context.Response.ContentType = movie.ImageFileType;
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(movie.ImageFile.ToArray());

    }        

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```